# How do I solo mine my own modified altcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, miner-configuration, genesis-block, dash

I forked **DASH** a week ago. I am able to generate genesis block hash, merkle hash. I created one VM (ubuntu 16.04) for rpc server. Another one VM For mining. I am able to establish connetion between two VMS's. But when I want to mine genesis block. I cant able to do so and I get the following error.

```
Launching miner...

[2018-08-09 12:03:38] Binding thread 2 to cpu 2
[2018-08-09 12:03:38] Binding thread 3 to cpu 3
[2018-08-09 12:03:38] Binding thread 1 to cpu 1
[2018-08-09 12:03:38] Binding thread 0 to cpu 0
[2018-08-09 12:03:38] 4 miner threads started, using 'X11' algorithm.
[2018-08-09 12:03:38] HTTP request failed: Failed to connect to 
192.168.0.105 port 80: Connection refused
[2018-08-09 12:03:38] json_rpc_call failed, retry after 30 seconds
```

I am currently trying to mine using ("minerd") provided by dash. Could anyone please help on how to solo mine using minerd or anyother app.

My Configuration for miner VM. (sampcoin.conf)

```
addnode=192.168.0.105
```

My Configuration for RPC VM. (sampcoin.conf)

```
server=1
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=password
listen=1
daemon=1
```

My Altcoin creation method based on this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDGxGYvkDEE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mining software (darcoin-cpu-miner- in dashpay github). It used **getwork** method. I changed to cpuminer which uses **getblocktemplate** and supports **x11** also. After that I run my altcoin mining. Then it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you won't implement a stratum on your server to connect in a "pool fashion" to your daemon you should use getwork or direct connection methods to mine.